# Django send multidimensional list data with form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django project rather complex project which involves a page with various form elements and graphical interface.

The graphical interface is basically an expandable matrix of rectangles in rows and columns which can be individually be turned off or on as well as being able to add/remove rows and columns. When the form is submitted I need some way to submit the state of the graphical interface. I have concluded that I can model the graphic using a multidimensional list such as:

`[[0,1,1,0], [0,1,1,1], [0,1,1,0], [1,1,1,1]]`

which would represent a 4x4 matrix with some panels on and some off.

My question is, given that I can get the current state of the matrix using jQuery, how should I send this data to the Django view when the whole form is submitted.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing an Ajax post of your form? or a regular post?

Comment: One option would be to use jQuery to populate a hidden form input to pass in the array to your view. If you were doing an Ajax post, you could add the array to the data posted.

Comment: What form field type should be used for the data?

Comment: You would want to use: forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)

Comment: OK - so populate a hidden text input field?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20263/discussion-between-brandon-and-darwin-tech)

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a regular form post, you'll need to copy the value for your layout array into an input that gets submitted with the form, preferably a hidden input as such:

```
$('#id_layout_preferences').val(layout_preferences);
```

Where id_layout_preferences is a Django form field:

```
layout_preferences = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

If you're doing an ajax post, you could just add the array as part of the post data that gets sent in the call along with all of the other form values.